# Can I set a timout value when using urllib3 and a socks proxy

Tags: python-3.x, urllib3

I managed to make a working script that checks if a socks5 proxy is up and running in python 3.x using urllib3. 
Now, I want to set up a timout value for the GET request, for example: check for 2 seconds if I don't get response I say that it doesnt work. Can I do that, if so how?

```
import pycurl
import urllib3
from urllib3.contrib.socks import SOCKSProxyManager

proxy = SOCKSProxyManager("socks5://96.113.176.101:1081/")
try:
    rslt = proxy.request('GET', 'http://google.com/humans.txt')
    if ('Google is built by a large team of engineers' in str(rslt.data)):
        print("Good proxy")
    else:
        print("Bad proxy")
except:
    print("Bad proxy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find a [useful documentation](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html?highlight=timeout#using-timeouts) , It seems that overriding the timout must be done when calling the get request function. There is a timout parameter and it is a float value in (seconds), ex: timout = 0.1 means 100ms:

```
import pycurl
import urllib3
from urllib3.contrib.socks import SOCKSProxyManager

proxy = SOCKSProxyManager("socks5://96.113.176.101:1080/")

try:
    rslt = proxy.request('GET', 'http://google.com/humans.txt', timeout=2.0)
    if ('Google is built by a large team of engineers' in str(rslt.data)):
        print("Good proxy")
    else:
        print("Bad proxy")
except Exception as e :
    print(e)
    print("Bad proxy")
```